# Python cron job logging

Tags: python, logging, cron

I have a python script that I'm setting up as a cron job and since cron jobs don't have a terminal to write standard output to I was wondering if there was a simple way to log the entirety of standard output in a text file. Basically, put everything that would be printed in the terminal if I ran this script myself in a text file that gets appended every time the cron job runs.

Comment: What about redirecting stdout to file using '>' operator? Stderr could redirected as well.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at python's standard [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file) module? It has handlers for logging to files (which you can then look at independently of the cronjob). It can also take custom handlers.